# How to publish ASP.NET website when TLS1.0 has been disabled

Tags: asp.net, ftp, visual-studio-2015, publishing, tls1.2

I have an ASP.NET website that I was happily publishing directly from visual studio 2015 until yesterday when my host turned off TLS 1.0 (they have TLS 1.1 and 1.2 enabled)

```
Publish Method: FTP
Server: ftps://myftpsite.com
```

How when I try to publish I get the error *"Secure connection was closed by the remote connection end."*

I tried turning TLS1.0 off in the Security section of the Advanced settings of Internet Explorer Options, but this seems to have no effect.

I can connect ok with FileZilla, but this seems to be auto negotiating a bit better.

is there any way I can publish directly from VS?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @OutstandingBill - no I have had to resort to publishing to disk and then using FileZilla

Comment: I've filed a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2353425) with Microsoft